# Using sharepoint search API, how to retrieve all documents within all sites within my sharepoint tenancy?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

The code snippet I have below is retrieving all documents in one document library inside one site.

I want to be able to retrieve all documents inside all document library's inside all my sites/tenancy.

```
  public getDocuments() {
    axios 
    .get("https://bpdev.sharepoint.com/sites/KIM/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList2')/items?$select=*,FileRef",
            { params:{},
              headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
            })
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        documents: response.data.d.results
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Any idea how to update my endpoint to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using content type id.

```
https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web ContentTypeId:0x0101*'
```

Here 0x0101*' is document content type id. If we create new content type it will start from 0x0101*.

Comment: I have updated my end point with your suggestion, however, the json/xml that is returned does not contain any of the documents from the KIM site?

Comment: bpdev.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentTypeId:0x0101*'

Comment: added 2 more property in querytext, try now adding it.